# Designing a recipe database

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, schema

I'm making a simple recipe app that allows user to create and save their recipes. I'm using SQLite if that makes any difference.

My database knowledge is a bit rusty so I've been looking around for inspiration in order to design an appropriate database.

One example that users here seem to point to is the following schema by Barry Williams: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/recipes/index.htm
This db is overly detailed so I decided to used only the following tables:

```
Recipe                 (recipe_id(PK), name, description)
Ingredient             (ingredient_id(PK), name)
Recipe_Steps           (recipe_id(PF), step_number(PK), instructions)
Recipe_Step_Ingredients(recipe_id(PF), step_number(PF), ingredient_id(PF), amount)
```

From my understanding, each ingredient is associated to a step in the recipe whereas I feel like each ingredient should be associated directly to a recipe and that the steps could be an attribute of the recipe table or in a Step table directly related to Recipe. Here would be my design:

```
Recipe                 (recipe_id(PK), name, description)
Ingredient             (ingredient_id(PK), name)
Recipe_Steps           (recipe_id(PF), step_number(PK), instructions)
Recipe_Ingredients     (recipe_id(PF), ingredient_id(PF), amount)
```

Mr. Williams knows much more about databases than I do so I don't know if I'm misunderstanding his schema and screwing it up with my version or if this all comes down to personal preference in design.

Is my version of the schema correct, if not, would you please be able to guide me towards the appropriate answer?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Schema depends from buisness model of your app. If each recipe step must have list of nessesary ingrediates first one is correct if not the second. So there is no correct answer.

Comment: Thanks for your input, Egor. I wanted to clarify, the basics of what I need are: the recipe name, a list of ingredients and a list of steps. Although the steps will mention some ingredients, I feel like it's more appropriate to have the ingredients listed in the recipe as opposed to the steps which are just directions on how to cook without referencing specific data. So I guess it just comes down to personal preference.

Comment: Yes, from my point of view your schema is better. As I know in real cookbooks ingrediates assosiated directly with recipes not with steps. But it depends from application requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the database schema I used to implement the AnyMeal recipe software:

```
PRAGMA user_version = 1;
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE recipes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, servings INTEGER NOT NULL, servingsunit VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE categories(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(40) UNIQUE NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE category(recipeid INTEGER NOT NULL, categoryid INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(recipeid, categoryid), FOREIGN KEY(recipeid) REFERENCES recipes(id), FOREIGN KEY(categoryid) REFERENCES categories(id));
CREATE TABLE ingredients(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name VARCHAR(60) UNIQUE NOT NULL);
CREATE TABLE ingredient(recipeid INTEGER NOT NULL, line INTEGER NOT NULL, amountint INTEGER NOT NULL, amountnum INTEGER NOT NULL, amountdenom INTEGER NOT NULL, amountfloat REAL NOT NULL, unit CHARACTER(2) NOT NULL, ingredientid INTEGER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(recipeid, line), FOREIGN KEY(recipeid) REFERENCES recipes(id), FOREIGN KEY(ingredientid) REFERENCES ingredients(id));
CREATE TABLE instruction(recipeid INTEGER NOT NULL, line INTEGER NOT NULL, txt TEXT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY(recipeid, line), FOREIGN KEY(recipeid) REFERENCES recipes(id));
CREATE TABLE ingredientsection(recipeid INTEGER NOT NULL, line INTEGER NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (recipeid, line), FOREIGN KEY(recipeid) REFERENCES recipes(id));
CREATE TABLE instructionsection(recipeid INTEGER NOT NULL, line INTEGER NOT NULL, title VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (recipeid, line), FOREIGN KEY(recipeid) REFERENCES recipes(id));
COMMIT;
```